# Fixed Header stays when scrolls but navigation doubles

Tags: css

I currently am using a fixed header for my website: http://www.destinykingproductions.com/test/ I have attached the css I currently have. Anyone have any suggestions on why this is happening?

```
#main {
   background-color: transparent; 
   margin-top: -40px; 
   height: auto; 
   max-height: none; 
   width: auto; 
   padding-bottom: 35px; 
} 

header#masthead {
   height: 103px; 
   background-image: url(http://www.destinykingproductions.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/header_bg1.jpg); 
   position: fixed; 
   z-index: 856; 
   width: 100%; 
   margin-top: 0px; 
   top: 0px; 
} 

nav.main-navigation {
   top: -200%; 
   background-color: transparent; 
   z-index: 4670; 
} 

nav.main-navigation ul.menu li {
   padding-left: 17px; 
} 

nav.main-navigation ul.menu {
   margin-left: 18%; 
} 

#shiftnav-toggle-main {
   display: none; 
}
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: your script is adding a secondary nav on scroll, check your JQuery code or better change the script, you really don't need it, you can accomplish that with pure CSS

Comment: There are 2 <nav> to your code... one is getting the class sticky and the onther is not... I believe some code are making it to double it...

Comment: i found ($$ = $$.clone().insertBefore($$);) in your theme-main-min.js i think this is the point where the second nav tag is comming form

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are correct - the "sticky" class nav is being added / toggled at some point.  When you add 'display:none' to that sticky class, then it is fine on a desktop view.  However, it looks like you are using that class for something with mobile because when the screen is resized smaller and back to normal then the side menu area doesn't go away.  It looks like you may want to move that sticky class to your 768px media query and/or have it not show on larger screens.

```
/*normal css*/
.main-navigation.sticky { display: none }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
    .main-navigation.sticky { display: block }
}
```